# Better Explanation of SwiftLint Opt-In Rules match_kinds setting

Tags: swift, swiftlint

Does anyone have a better explanation of the match_kinds types for the Opt-In rules of SwiftLint. The documentation gives the enumerated types, but no explanation other than names.

The match_kinds types include:

argument, attribute.builtin, attribute.id, buildconfig.id, buildconfig.keyword, comment, comment.mark, comment.url, doccomment, doccomment.field, identifier, keyword, numberobjectliteral, parameter, placeholder, string, string_interpolation_anchor, typeidentifier

For example, I want to have the scope that searched for specific keywords before specific named function.

Comment: I'd love to know more about these as well.

Comment: likewise, they're not defined by SwiftLint, rather they come from Apple's SourceKit, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation that explains them from that either.